# How can I create database for fetching single student marks

Tags: php, sql

I want to fetch single student marks from SQL table for all subjects, but my problem is all subject are saved in one column in SQL database as shown in an image below

How can I fetch all subject marks for single student from database?

listen...........

```
id name subject marks
1  xyz  a1      12
2  xyz1  a2     22
3  xyz  a3      33
4  xyz1  a4     11
5 xyz  a5      55
6  xyz1  a6     10
```

I want display xyz student all subject marks how I fetch xyz all subject marks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: chk image you can understand what i am saying i need to fetch one student mark for all subject but in my sql database its not possible

Comment: Telling us to re-read the question doesn't make the question more clear.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What are your desired results?  What is preventing you from achieving those results?  Why can't you simply `SELECT` from the table `WHERE` a "student" identifier equals a given "student"?  Wouldn't that give you all of the records (subjects/marks/whatever) for that student in that table?

Comment: problem is my subject save in one coloum in database like, eng,science etc etc so how i get single student ,all subject marks when all subject save in one coloum i get only one marks can you see image which i attach in my post than you able to understand what am asking

Comment: So then each *row* is a subject for a student, right?  So select all of the rows for that student and you will have all of the subjects for that student.  Where is the problem?  Are you just looking for the WHERE keyword?

Comment: listen...........

id name subject marks

1  xyz  a1      12

2  xyz1  a2     22

3  xyz  a3      33

4  xyz1  a4     11

5 xyz  a5      55

6  xyz1  a6     10

now i want display xyz student all subject marks how i fetch xyz all subject marks 
hope you go it

Comment: So you want all records where the `name` is `"xyz"`?  That would be: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='xyz'`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fetch all subject marks for single student from database?

You'd use a `WHERE` clause to filter the records to just the ones you want.  So if this is your current total set:

```
id name  subject marks
1  xyz   a1     12
2  xyz1  a2     22
3  xyz   a3     33
4  xyz1  a4     11
5  xyz   5      55
6  xyz1  a6     10
```

And you want all records with `name` equal to `xyz`:

```
id name  subject marks
1  xyz   a1     12
3  xyz   a3     33
5  xyz   5      55
```

Then you would `SELECT` from that table "where name equals xyz":

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'xyz'
```